# SQL Server: How to find what lines are executed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, code-coverage, statements

I am working on a mutation test framework for SQL Server, for this I need to be able to calculate what lines of a stored procedure, function or trigger are executed when I execute a certain stored procedure.

The difficult part is that I want to know the exact lines or statements being executed from the stored procedure I call.

With a query like this I can see what stored procedures/triggers/functions are being executed, since I know when I call the stored procedure I can use the time to see if it was executed.

```
SELECT  d.object_id, d.database_id, 
         OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) AS proc_name, 
         MAX( d.last_execution_time) as last_execution_time,
         OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) as definition
         FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d 
         WHERE d.database_id = DB_ID()
         GROUP BY  d.object_id, d.database_id, 
         OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id)
```

How would I find the lines/statements that have been executed, I also have to know inside what stored procedure/trigger/function the lines/statements exists and in which shema this is. I have to take into account that a IF/ELSE statement may be used.

With this data I can do 2 important things:

- generate a code coverage report
- optimize what lines to mutate, since I dont have to mutate uncovered lines.

A possible, but not a very nice, solution would be to automaticly change stored procedures to add a line that inserts the previous line into a table, but this will require splitting up the procedure into statements, which I don't know how to do.

Please note that I cannot change the code users want to test with my framework. I can search for patterns and replace but manually changing procedures is NOT a option.

EDIT:
Lets redifine this question: How to split a stored procedure definition into its different statements in a way that does not depend on code style?
and How to add a new statement in between found statements?

EDIT: in the SO post [SQL Server: How to parse code into its different statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855382/sql-server-how-to-parse-code-into-its-different-statements) I have found a way to trace statement execution, but I can't filter it yet.

Comment: What do you mean "what lines are executed"? SQL isn't a programming language, it's a query language. When you the data engine is given a statement it parses the whole thing and decides internally the "best" way to get the results requested. What are you *actually* asking here? What is your question?

Comment: You could use Profiler to run a trace or Extended Events.

Comment: I am talking about tSQL which means that besides queries you actually write procedural code. I need to know what branches of if statements are executed, what exceptions are thrown

Comment: But I also need to know what queries are executed

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some kind of logging into **all** of your SPs then to store what `IF` statements are entered. That'll mean changing every one of your SPs that has an `IF` statement (or similar procedure flow operator).

Comment: How would I split up a procedure so that I can recognise try, catch, if, else and similar statements. Since not all of them will use BEGIN END and I may need to add those

Comment: I think you could use the `sp_statement_starting` Extended Event. With that event, you get line_number, offset, and offset_end which you should be able to use to get to the lines that were executed in the sproc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the extended events are the solution, this is how I have done it:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.server_event_sessions WHERE name='testMSSQLTrace')  
   DROP EVENT SESSION testMSSQLTrace ON SERVER;  

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @cmd = 'CREATE EVENT SESSION testMSSQLTrace 
ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed
        (WHERE (sqlserver.database_name = N''' + DB_NAME() + '''))
    ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
        WITH (
            MAX_MEMORY = 2048 KB,
            EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = NO_EVENT_LOSS,
            MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 3 SECONDS,
            MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB,
            MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE,
            TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
            STARTUP_STATE = OFF
        );'

EXEC (@cmd)
```

This creates an event that can be fired after every statement completion, this is done dynamicly to filter on the database

Then I have 3 procedures that make controlling this event easy

```
/*******************************************************************************************
    Starts the statement trace
*******************************************************************************************/
CREATE OR ALTER PROC testMSSQL.Private_StartTrace
AS
BEGIN 
    ALTER EVENT SESSION testMSSQLTrace
          ON SERVER
        STATE = START; 
END
GO

/*******************************************************************************************
    Ends the statement trace, this also clears the trace
*******************************************************************************************/
CREATE OR ALTER PROC testMSSQL.Private_StopTrace
AS
BEGIN
    ALTER EVENT SESSION testMSSQLTrace
          ON SERVER
        STATE = STOP; 
END
GO


/*******************************************************************************************
    Saves the statements trace
*******************************************************************************************/
CREATE OR ALTER PROC testMSSQL.Private_SaveTrace
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml XML;

    SELECT @xml = CAST(xet.target_data AS xml)
        FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)  
        WHERE xe.name = 'testMSSQLTrace'  

    INSERT INTO testMSSQL.StatementInvocations (testProcedure, procedureName, lineNumber, statement)
        SELECT testMSSQL.GetCurrentTest(), 
            OBJECT_NAME(T.c.value('(data[@name="object_id"]/value)[1]', 'int')),
            T.c.value('(data[@name="line_number"]/value)[1]', 'int'), 
            T.c.value('(data[@name="statement"]/value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(900)')
        FROM @xml.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event') T(c)
        WHERE T.c.value('(data[@name="nest_level"]/value)[1]', 'int') > 3

END
GO
```

These procedures respectivly start and stop the trace and the last one stores the result in a table where it filters on the nest level so my own code is not traced.

Finally I use it a bit like this:

```
start trace
start tran/savepoint
run SetUp (users code)
run test (users code)
save trace
save trace to variable
rollback tran (also catch errors and stuff like that)
save variable back to table so the trace is not rolled back
```

Special thanks to @Jeroen Mosterd for originally coming up with a proposal for this solution in this [SQL Server: How to parse code into its different statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855382/sql-server-how-to-parse-code-into-its-different-statements/56951052#56951052) SO post

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Add a **@DEBUG** parameter to each stored procedure you call, or
- Log everything you want, or
- Only log when you want.

With the @Debug parameter, you can default it to OFF, then call it with ON when you want to trace your statements, with the following code:

```
IF (@Debug = 1) PRINT 'your tracing information goes here';
```

If you want to log everything, create a log table and insert a row into it wherever you need to know which statement was executed, such as:

```
DECLARE @log AS TABLE (msg VARCHAR(MAX));
```

and

```
INSERT INTO @log VALUES('your tracing information goes here');
```

Or you can combine them:

```
IF (@Debug = 1) INSERT INTO @log VALUES('your tracing information goes here');
```

Of course these will affect performance even when you don't output/log.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I dont write all the stored procedures, this project is about testing other peoples code, so I cant affect the way they write code. This answer will not work for me.

Comment: LOL, minor detail (not).

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready to go [SqlCover](https://github.com/GoEddie/SQLCover) solution which does everything you described:

- it starts an ExtendedEvents session and collects actual statement execution events
- it parses existing TSQL objects and performs matching between the code and the `sp_statement_starting` event details
- in the end you have `coverage.opencoverxml` report

It works good enough, we use it in combination with [tSQLt](https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt) testing framework. Coverage report we deliver to [SonarQube](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.9/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/generic-test-data/) where we have [this plugin for tsql code](https://github.com/gretard/sonar-sql-plugin) installed.

However you cannot catch *every line* execution, every possible code flow because `sp_statement_starting/completed` is the highest detalization provided by XEvents and *statement level* is the best you can get. Thus, for example, if there was `MERGE` executed you don't really know which of `WHEN...THEN...` actions were fired, if there is a `CASE` you don't know which `WHEN...THEN...` worked and so on, only that the whole statement was executed. This makes "coverage" results not really reliable but as of 2024 this is the best you can get in TSQL.